# exif-js orientation always returns 0 on android but works on desktop

Tags: javascript, android, exif

I'm using exif-js library to extract the orientation from images uploaded to my web app.
I need the exif orientation to rotate incorrectly rotated android images.

The problem is that images uploaded from android device always return 0 as their orientation.

I've tried transfering image taken from the same android device to desktop, and uploading it from there, everything works fine in that case and I get the orientation 6.

```
localforage.getItem('photo').then(function(value) {
                alert('inside forage');
            image = value;
            alert(image); // i get the image object
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
            alert(url); // url is correct
                let preview = document.getElementById('camera-feed');
                preview.src = url;
                // const tags = ExifReader.load(image);
                console.log( tags );
            EXIF.getData(image, function() {
               myData = this;
                 if (myData.exifdata.Orientation) {
                        orientation = parseInt(EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation"));
                        alert(orientation); // on desktop 6, on android always 0
                 }
            });
            ....
```

I'm using chrome browser on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of changes in my project, I used 
 [this](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/blob/master/js/load-image-orientation.js) library to handle image rotation on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved this, but I would still like to recommend [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) library if you need more than orientation. Or if performance is important to you. Exifr is fast and can handle hundreds of photos without crashing the browser or taking a long time :). Plus there's neat simple API and you feed it with pretty much anything -  element, URL, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, even base64 url or string and more.

```js
exifr.orientation(file).then(val => {
  console.log('orientation:', val)
})
```